# Circle of Apollonius proof question

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, locus

Im reading a proof of the [Circle of Apollonius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius) and I am unsure of one part of it -

Find the locus of a point P whose distances from two fixed points, A and A' are in a ratio of 1 : $\mu$.

Define a points A1 and A2 on line AA' such that A1P bisects the internal angle APA' and A2P bisects the external angle APA'. Then define points E and F on AP such that A'E is parallel to A1P and A'F is parallel to A2p, **that is, perpendicular to A1P**.

From this we have $\frac{AA1}{A1A'}=\frac{AP}{PE}=\frac{AP}{PA'}=\frac{AP}{FP}=\frac{AA2}{A'A2}=\frac{1}{\mu}$

Since **$\angle A1PA2$ is a right angle**, P lies on a circle with diameter A1A2.

My question is, how do we know $\angle A1PA2$ is a right angle? I can see how it follows that it is a right angle after saying A'F is perpendicular to A1p, but I dont understand how we get that either.

Edit: Sorry I don't have a diagram to go with this, its from my book. The diagram on the third page of [this](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa09/KimB/EMAT6690/Essay2/6690%20apollonius%20circle.pdf) explanation is fairly close

Comment: __Hint:__ Half of the angle on a straight line is a right angle.

Comment: @CalvinLin I still don't see it. I dont think we get half an angle on a striaght line, we get half an arbitrary interior angle, and half an exterior angle that supplements it, meaning both angles (and their halfs) are arbitrary, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $A_1P$ is the internal angle bisector of $\angle APA'$. $A_2P$ is the external angle bisector of $\angle APA'$.

Hence $\angle A_1 P A_2  = \frac{ 180^\circ} {2} = 90^\circ$.

Comment: Why does it equal $\frac{180}{2}$?

Comment: @Dgrin91 Work it out. Let $\angle APA' = \alpha$. Write out all the angles in terms of $\alpha$.

Comment: Ahh, I see. No more math after 1 am for me :)

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the internal angle and the exterior angle is 180.

If you bisect internal angle and the exterior angle, then you've essentially divided 180 in half.